# SQL Server returning a value and checking if exists on the same select (one select operation)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with employees. This table has a column (FlagActive) which is of BIT type and indicates if employee is currently active (1) or inactive (0).

For example, to simplify the scenario, the table would be:

> Id | EmployeeName | FlagActive

I have a stored procedure that checks if employee exists in the table. If exists it does some stuff. Otherwise it does other stuff. So I do as follows:

```
DECLARE @IsActive BIT
SELECT @IsActive = FlagActive FROM Employees WHERE Id = @IdEmployee

IF @IsActive  = 1 
BEGIN
     -- Employee is active: Do some stuff
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- Employee is inactive: Do some stuff
END
```

It works welll if employee always exists on table but when in case of employee does not exists on table @IsActive = 0 is satisfied and ELSE body is executed. This is incorrect: if employee does not exists, nothing should be done.

Then I try to do below:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Employees WHERE Id = @IdEmployee)
BEGIN
   DECLARE @IsActive BIT    
   SELECT @IsActive = FlagActive FROM Employees WHERE Id = @IdEmployee

   IF @IsActive  = 1 
   BEGIN
       -- Employee is active: Do some stuff
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
       -- Employee is inactive: Do some stuff
   END
END
```

The problem with this approach is that I need to do 2 operations: first select to check if employee exists and second (once I know employee exists in table) to check if employee is active or inactive.

I would like to do these two operations in on select operation (same select) and avoid doing two select operations.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could change your IF Exists to just a select Active where employeeId = Id , if it is NULL they don't exist, else select the active value.

Comment: Please see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--You could change your IF Exists to just a select Active where employeeId = Id , 
--if it is NULL they don't exist, else select the active value.

 DECLARE @isActive BIT

--Instead of IF EXISTS, just set the BIT value to whatever is returned,
--If NULL they don't exist
SET @isActive =  SELECT TOP 1 [FlagActive] FROM Employees WHERE Id = @IdEmployee

   IF @isActive IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN

       IF @IsActive  = 1 
       BEGIN
          -- Employee is active: Do some stuff
       END
       ELSE
       BEGIN
          -- Employee is inactive: Do some stuff
       END
   END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change your else like that :

```
ELSE IF @IsActive = 0 AND @IsActive IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
     -- Employee is inactive: Do some stuff
END
```

Comment: It does not work because if employee does not exist in the table, then @IsActive gets 0 (@IsActive = 0) and not null and else body is executed.

Comment: This `SELECT @IsActive = FlagActive FROM Employees WHERE Id = @IdEmployee` if employee doesnt exist set @IsActive on NULL @user1624552

Comment: Very sorry, you are right. I did not checked it well. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad I could help you :) @user1624552